# Removing duplicate keys based on value in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have an RDD given by parallelizing a list of key-value pairs [(1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2,0)] and I want to remove tuples with the same key based on their value (so for tuples with the same key, only that which has the lowest value stays). So I want to apply a transformation such that the RDD is represented by [(1,0), (2,0)] in the end (I don't care about ordering here as long as the correct copies are removed). Currently, what I am doing is calling

```
RDD = RDD.map(lambda (x, y): (y, x)).sortByKey().map(lambda (x, y): (y, x)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x)
```

The first three transformations let me sort by value and the last simply removes duplicate keys (since my tuples are ordered by value now tuple copies with the smallest value stay in tact). This works fine, but I feel like doing this is definitely overcomplicating things and resulting in overpriced performance. Does anyone have any idea how to simplify this a bit more? Help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `rdd.reduceByKey(Math.min(_,_))` too simple for an answer

Comment: @aaronman  +1 - Could put that on an answer so that the question can be marked as accepted?.

Comment: @Leeren You didn't mention how your RDD is partitioned, and how you want it to be partitioned after this operation. If you don't care, the above solution is fine, but it will introduce communication while re-partitioning. Depending on your needs you may want to make sure the original RDD is partitioned by key (using a custom Partitioner) and then use RDD's mapPartitions method to reduce, Each instance of the lambda will have to deal with several different keys, but all instances of a key will be in the same partition.

Comment: @maasg done, I was kinda hoping he would just delete the question or something

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov partitioning and then mapping is not as efficient as reduce by key, because it doesn't allow spark to use combiners, which can **significantly** reduce the amount of data sent over the network

Comment: @aaronman: Point taken, but we don't know where the data comes from and in what form. Since it's an RDD it's _already_ partitioned in some way, and Leeren may have had a choice in how it got partitioned when creating it or reading it from a database -- or even when it was stored. I wasn't proposing that an extra re-partitioning step be added _just_ to make the reduce more efficient. Rather I wanted to make sure Leeren had considered the partitioning strategy and how it may impact other choices.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov good point if the data was already stored in a partitioned fashion you can skip the shuffle step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple, basically 
`rdd.reduceByKey(Math.min(_,_))` -- This is for scala

In python I guess it would be
`rdd.reduceByKey(lambda (x,y) : min(x,y))`